# codeignietor cart only one product is adding to cart

Tags: codeigniter

while doing a cart page i am able to add only one product to cart class,antor product is not entering the class.My controller,model 
    controller class
    public function buy($id){

```
        $product = $this->mproduct->find($id);
        $res['result'] = $product;

        $data = array(
           'id'      => $product->pro_id,
           'qty'     => '1',
           'price'   => $product->pro_price,
           'name'    => $product->pro_title,

        );
    $array =  (array) $data;
    $this->cart->insert($array);
    $this->load->view('cart',$res);



    }

    public function delete($row_id){
        $this->cart->update(array('rowid' => $row_id,'qty' => 0));
        $this->load->view('cart');
    }


    public function update(){

        $i=1;
        foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items) {

            $this->cart->update(array('rowid' =>$items['rowid'],'qty' => $_POST['qty'.$i]));
            $i++;

        }
        $this->load->view('cart');
    }
```

The Model

```
public function find($id)
{
    $this->db->where('pro_id',$id);
    return $this->db->get('products')->row();

}
```

Comment: Possibly down to the `'qty'     => '1',` part which is always setting the quantity to 1?

Comment: yes its qty 1.right